Bounded in probability with the deteministic notation
I study the paper in the link below:
https://projecteuclid.org/journals/bernoulli/volume-24/issue-2/Smooth-backfitting-for-additive-modeling-with-small-errors-in-variables/10.3150/16-BEJ898.full
The result of the Proposition 1 (page 1241) in this paper is
\begin{aligned}
\max_{1 \leq i \leq n}|\hat{\xi}^i_{jk}-{\xi}_{jk}^i|=O_p(n^{-(\beta-1)/(2\beta)}), \quad 1\leq j\leq d,1 \leq k \leq L_j, \beta \geq 2.
\end{aligned}
But, in the proof of the Lemma 1 (page 1256), the paper states like this:
We may assume that $\max_{i,j,k} |\hat{\xi}^i_{jk}-{\xi}_{jk}^i| \leq C_0 n^{−(\beta−1)/(2\beta)}$
for some positive constant $C_0$ , due to Proposition 1.
I wonder how this is possible. Generally $\max_{i,j,k} |\hat{\xi}^i_{jk}-{\xi}_{jk}^i| = O_p(n^{−(\beta−1)/(2\beta)})$                 doesn't imply                   $\max_{i,j,k} |\hat{\xi}^i_{jk}-{\xi}_{jk}^i| \leq C_0 n^{−(\beta−1)/(2\beta)}$. I was thinking about defining the event using $C_0$ with probability tending to one, but I still couldn't find the solution.So, basically it seems like the paper claims that $X_n=O_p(1)$ implies $|X_n| \leq C_0$ for some fixed constant $C_0 > 0$. Intuitively, it seems like that the particular choice of $C_0$ cannot change the proof and that's why the paper claims that we may assume. but, how to express this mathematically?

For any $\epsilon>0$, there is some $C_\epsilon$ such that $$\mathbb P\left(\max_{i,j,k} |\hat{\xi}^i_{jk}-{\xi}{jk}^i| \leq C\epsilon n^{−(\beta−1)/(2\beta)}\right)\geq 1-\epsilon.$$ Since the authors' goal is to derive $O_p$ statements from the existing one in Proposition 1, you should be able to fill the missing details, by controlling the constants and the probability of the events involved.
